# Google Apps Script close HTML window without button, on demand

Tags: html, google-apps-script

for some time I've been struggling how to properly run and close "Loader 360". First I will write some basic informations

My assumptions

- I would like to have only 1 HTML file with loader
- I would like to use it in different functions

How I see it should work

1. Rune some function
2. Run Loader
3. Send information to close loader

How I handle with this problem at this moment (I hate this solution but at this moment I don't know how to manage it in different way)

I have 3 different functions (code below)

1. Open Loader
2. Close Loader
3. Open loader with automatic close window when function stops.

I have 3 different HTML files (for the same Loader)

1. Run Loader
2. To close Loader
3. Loader is closed automatically when the function stops.

So now when I run function and I would like to have a loader when this function is  runned I do something like this:

```
runLoader();
someFunction();
closeLoader();
```

but as you can see this solution is not so pretty because I have 2x HTML files for exactly the same thing.
For one function I have separate 3rd HTML with an extra script which closes a window when the function stops, and I can't imagine making the same for eg20 different functions.

Do you have any suggestions on how to handle this problem ?

[image]

**Function to start loader**

```
function runLoader() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('Loader360')
    .setWidth(215)
    .setHeight(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Loading...');
      }
```

**Function to close loader**

```
function closeLoader() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('CloseLoader360')
    .setWidth(215)
    .setHeight(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Loading...');
}
```

**HTML - Open Loader 360**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <meta name="viewport">
  <style>
    .loader {
      border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      /* Safari */
      animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
        /* Safari */
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
          100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
        @keyframes spin {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
          100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
    <body>
      <div class="loader"></div>
  <script>
          </script>
</body>
    </html>
```

**HTML - Close Loader 360**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <meta name="viewport">
  <style>
    .loader {
      border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      /* Safari */
      animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
        /* Safari */
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
          100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
        @keyframes spin {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
          100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
    <body>
      <div class="loader"></div>
  <script>
         setTimeout(function(){ google.script.host.close(); },0.1)
          </script>
</body>
    </html>
```

**code in HTML used to run one function**

```
<script>
              google.script.run
                .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
                .applayBomTemplateToAllRows();
                </script>
```

**Example**

```
function onEdit(e) {

  //Get Sheet Basic ifnormation
  let activeSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  let activeSheetName = activeSheet.getName();

  // Get sheet information
  let rowNumberWithModification = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
  let columnNumberWithModification = preadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn();

  if ((rowNumberWithModification === 1) && (columnNumberWithModification === 1)) {
    runLoader(); //Here I would like to run a loader because I know that next function will take some time and I would like to inform user that something is calculating in background
    setDescription(); //function set for example red color of the font 
    closeLoader();
  }
  else {
    runLoader();
    usePainter(); //Painter will set a correct shape of the, let say 10rows
    closeLoader();
  }
}
```

Comment: What or where are these "different functions" and how are they called?

Comment: There are a several functions, for example one function set description in correct column (depends what user has set). Other one set correct formulas, other one use a painter etc... That's why I wanted to have one HTML withe with loader and call it when I need.

Comment: How are they called?

Comment: I have a function onEdit(e) and it checks if user set some new values for example in col 1 row 1 if yes then I run setDescription()....

Comment: Could you [edit] to add such code as a [mcve] with explanations?

Comment: ok, I have added a simple code, but please be aware that there will be a several cases when this loader is gonna be run. Here you can see only 2 cases but at the end probably there will be ~20 cases when I would like to run this "loader" that's why I wanted to have only 1 HTML file

Comment: I agree with @TheWizEd solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might I suggest a modified procedure.  I don't know where `runLoader()` is executed but that is really all you need.  Then there is only 1 HTML. When the page loads it runs the spinner and `google.script.run` to run `someFunction()`.  When `someFunction` completes it runs the callback function in the client and closes the spinner.

I have edited my answer to address the question about using loader with different functions.

I use templated HTML to pass a variable `option` to the HTML Template to tell it which option has been selected.  That option is then passed back to the client to tell it which function to run.

So in answer to the question, no additional HTML files are necessary.

I tested the method of calling variable functions proposed by TheMaster and it works.  I've edited my answer to include it as it shows a more elegant way of doing it.

It took me a little while to wrap my head around it but then I realized

`google.script.run().someFunction()` is equivalent to `google.script.run()["someFunction"]()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      .... put all your style stuff here
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <script>
      let option = <?= option ?>;  // <- this line was added
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
        function() {
          google.script.host.close();
        }
      )[option]();  // <- add option added here
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs

```
function onEdit(e) {

  // your code here

  if ((rowNumberWithModification === 1) && (columnNumberWithModification === 1)) {
    runLoader("setDescription");
  }
  else {
    runLoader("usePainter");
  }
}

function runLoader(option) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('Loader360')
    .setWidth(215)
    .setHeight(200);
  htmlOutput.option = option;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput.evaluate(), 'Loading...');
}

function setDescription() {
  // do something
}

function usePainter() {
  // do something else
}
```

Reference

- [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: If I'm not wrong with this solution I will have to create several HTML files with loader because it will run loader with specific function. I forgot to add that I will use it in google sheets to have a specific Bill of Materials, and I want to run it when I want to have it because I know that calculations will take a some time.

Comment: Currently I have this solution for one function but how you would like to use this "loader" when you would like to use different function and display for user information in this case  "loader" that some calculations are run i background ?
  <script>
    google.script.run
                .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
                .applayBomTemplateToAllRows();
  </script>

Comment: I have edited by answer to address you questions.

Comment: +1. Suggestion to directly call the function like this: ``google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(         function() {           google.script.run.close();         }       )[option]()``  You can eliminate the ``switch case function`` completely. Edit:or simply `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.run.close)[option]()`

Comment: @TheMaster, thanks for the suggestion.  I learned something new today.

Comment: It works perfectly, thx a lot :), I have just found one small mistake in HTML file, to close window should be `google.script.host.close();`  instead `google.script.run.close();`

Comment: I changed it to `google.script.host.close()`.  Thanks